# Google alerts api for .net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to build an  application in .net, and using google alerts (the feeds part).
Right now i am searching for API, or some way to interact with google alerts, but no results so far.

It will be very good if anyone can provide me with that google alerts API.
OR
A way to interact with it.

Thanks in advance,
-Sea

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your alert set the delivery method to feed, this will create a standard RSS feed which you can consume using an XmlTextReader or XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

There is a .net implementation of an api for google alerts here: http://coders11.com/googlealertsapi

Comment: Disappointing: "You can buy a full commercial license without limits for 60€/80USD"

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before and its easy to use and works great 
http://frickingnutz.com/?q=node/51

Answer (score 0):

There is Google Alert API for C#:
https://github.com/oscar811/GoogleAlertAPI

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.